# MYSQL: 30 day moving average stock prices

Tags: mysql

Objective to select the average closing price of last 30 trading days for each stock, based on input date NOT latest date

Given that;

1) If the input date is 2015-09-18, to select average closing price of last 30 TRADING days, e.g. (2015-09-18, 2015-09-17, 2015-09-16,...30 days)

2) If the input date is 2015-09-01, to select average closing price of last 30 TRADING days, e.g. (2015-09-01, 2015-09-31, 2015-09-28,...30 days)

3) Table columns:  ticker | code | date | open | high | low | close | volume

4) Table contains records for only TRADING days, weekends and holidays are excluded

5) For each stock, there are thousands of days of records, but we just want the 30 Day MA at any given point in time

```
Input date: 2015-09-01
Desired output

date     | ticker | code |  30 day average closing price 
2015-09-01  AAA    1122     1.33
2015-09-01  BBB    3344     0.79
... 
...
...and so on for each stock
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starting point see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add these functions. Should be like (not tested):

```
SELECT `date`, ticker, avg(`close`) from TRADES where
date <= '2015-09-01' and date >= DATE_SUB('2015-09-01', INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY ticker
```

Comment: That only works if each and every day is a trading day. I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks Alex but that wont work because the table only stores trading days. Date sub will factor in weekends so a 30 day subtraction will result in less than 30 days

Comment: After over 10 hours of research, i found out how to do it the way i want it but it was too slow for the query to execute. in the end i settled for 2nd best option which is to run date sub for 40+ days and i will get +/- 30 days which is good enough. Thanks Axel

Answer (score 0):

EDIT
This version should be flexible and I hope not too slow. Since no idea what means what in your table and how the table is called, I assume a table pricetable with code='AAA','BBB' and so and `close` meaning the price. Your given date should be '2015-09-12' here. Replace '2015-09-12' whith whatever you like.

30 should be the number of trading days. Replace by whatever you want in 'limit 30'.

ticker | code | date | open | high | low | close | volume

***TRY THIS VERSION***

```
select pt.code, sum(pt.close) / count(*) as average
from pricetable pt 
inner join 
  ( select distinct `date`
    from pricetable 
    where `date` <= '2015-09-12' # your given date
    order by `date` desc 
    limit 30 # the number of trading days
  ) as  d on d.`date` = pt.`date`
where code in ("AAA","BBB","CCC")
group by code
order by average desc;
```

Use some of the latter versions if the subselect get too slow.

You definitely should make a table with calendar days, and they get a column to mark trading days. It would be much easier if they also contain a reference to the 30-day-before and the 90-day-before.

```
 create table calendar_days 
 (
    id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, 
    calday date not null, 
    is_trading tinyint, 
    trading_before_30 date, 
    trading_before_90 date
 );
```

Then it gets easy:

```
select pt.stockname, sum(pt.closing_price) / count(*) as avg_close
from calendar_days d
inner join pricetable pt on pt.day between d.calday and d.trading_before_30
where d.calday = '2015-08-15'
group by pt.stockname;
```

You can fill that calendar day table quite easy from your stock table.

EDIT: this way you can fill it at first requests of day, assuming that *only* trading days are in this table.

```
insert into calendar_days (calday, is_trading) 
select distinct day, 1
from pricetable pt 
where pt.day > (select max(calday from calendar_days);

update calendar_days d1 
inner join calendar_days d2 on d2.nr = d1.nr - 29
set d1.trading_before_30 = d2.calday 
where d1.trading_before_30 is null;
```

You could of course try to dynamically construct a list of the last 30 trading days out of your stockprice table, but that table has many many entries per day, so that would be a unneccessary slow down of your query - the day changes very seldom, just once every day.

You could even add a trigger to your closing day table so that on every insert it will check if calendar days are to be refilled.

A version without that table would look like:

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_days;
create temporary table tmp_days (tradingday date not null primary key);
insert into tmp_days 
select distinct `day` 
from pricetable 
where day <= '2015-08-15'
order by day desc limit 30;
```

and then

```
select pt.stockname, sum(pt.price) / count(*) as average
from pricetable pt 
inner join tmp_days d on d.tradingday = pt.day;
```

The temp-table will be only visible in one connection.

Comment: flaschenpost, thanks but tht wont work it is best to store only trading days as it is easier to maintain the table. not all holidays are known in advance, there could be sometimes ad hoc holidays

Comment: I have up to this point:

SELECT *
FROM dailydata
WHERE date <= '2015-09-18' AND code='1122' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30 
) t1

but there's only 1 problem, it works for only 1 stock at a time which is 1122. i need it to output all stocks for each DISTINCT(code) in 1 go

Comment: @user6890 I added version with temp-table without fixed table, but this will slow down a bit. I even could merge this into subselect.

Comment: flaschenpost, the solution is not so flexible if i were to make variants for example instead of 30MA..i need a 23 MA....instead of close MA, i may need MA of volume... however.. i have found a partial solution from here: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

there is still 1 problem from that page.. which is

this line : country_rank := IF(current_country = country, country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,

current_country is alwaus NULL which results in country_rank always being 1. if u can help me solve the problem from the link i will have the final solution to share

Comment: @user6890 I like variables, I just can not see why they are needed here. Your request is about average for last 30 days of a given date. Do you need it for a list of days? I mean one stock, and the moving average for several successing dates? Then I would go for variables, but only then.

Comment: I need it for any given date, whichever date i input, the MA will be calculated from that point backwards.

The issue here is to be able to select N records of a stock. Forget the MA part.
I just need to know how can i select an output of N records, e.g

there are 2 stocks only (aaa & bbb), each stock has 5 days of data...
How can i select 1st 2 days of aaa and bbb ONLY... if this is solved.. the rest is solved

Comment: Then try the solution with subselect and tell if it works. Date and length are flexible.

Comment: I know that i need to use the sub select. the big problem is how to construct the sub select

Comment: I marked it as 'try this version' it is complete with subselect.

Comment: Bro, that looks promising however the line where code in ("AAA","BBB","CCC") implies that its static? what if they are more stocks than aaa,bbb & ccc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90108/discussion-between-user6890-and-flaschenpost).